# Why isn't the shadow being rendered?

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I've used this tutorial to do a toon shader:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJTEJKQ0lYw

I have this in my shading tab:
[image]

The shading appears just fine in the Material Preview (although mind that for some reason it doesn't move with the light...).
[image]

But once I render it (Eevee), only the highlight appears.

[image]

Is there perhaps some kind of step I did wrong?

EDIT:
If I add lightsources with a negative value, they'll throw a shadow even in rendered mode. However I don't understand why it doesnt work with a regular light source.

EDIT 2.0:
Nevermind, with the negative lighting added it works in the Render Preview, but once actually rendered the shadows are gone again.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. I didn't see the glossy shader at first. What is the reason in the video for using it? I don't often see glossy BSDF's in toon shaders.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett there's a glossy and a diffuse shader! the glossy was being used for the highlights (ironically thats only one being rendered right now...)

Comment: Do you have a light source and a ground plane? (Not the world)

Comment: @Yohello1 I do have a lightsource (thats where the highlights come from). I'm not sure what you mean by a ground plane, if you mean just a regular plane for the model to stand on, then yes!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant

Comment: @alex Read the pinned comment on the video

Comment: @Yohello1 Yea I saw that! However I put the 'Shadow Mode' on 'None' and even tried hiding/remoxing the outline completely and it still didn't work. Thanks, though!

Comment: Can you try cycles and increasing the power of the lightsource?

Comment: @Yohello1 I tried, however since the tutorial was for Eevee, it's pretty broken once I switch to Cycles. The outline causes everything to go black and with the outline hidden it looks like this
https://puu.sh/GrCIg/d94fa262fb.jpg

Comment: It seems you don't have the same lights in preview (from right) and render (from left). Sure all your lights are active for rendering or some hidden in preview?

Comment: @lemon i THINK the preview just uses a standard lighting... I did double check, though, and yes I have all lights visible, although I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'active for rendering'

Comment: @alex, can enable/disable things for previews (including rendered viewport shading) and the "real" render. But not sure this is your case, though